# Is there any shortcut key in mac for generating javadoc for overridden methods in android?

Tags: java, android

In Android Studio, i want to add javadoc above the **overridden methods**, i am searching for any shortcut key, for example in case of `onCreateView()` method below,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_paypeople_summary, container, false);
}
```

Comment: I am using Android Studio in mac mini. I found there is one way using Ctrl+O but it works only if method is not overridden. is there any way in this case, adding javdoc if method is already overridden?

Answer (score 2):

Try following methods :

> <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

OR

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! really appreciated.

Comment: yes it is solved, just need to override that method again, because it does not shows that method in list, if it is already overridden.

Comment: Of course. How will you be able to override it again? And please mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem, so that others can find answer to this question easily.

Comment: yes i have marked it, share if you know any idea to generate javadoc if method is already overridden.

Comment: You can not override one method two times in same java file.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `/** {@inheritDoc} */` or `{@link  package.class#member  label}`

[http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#{@inheritDoc}](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@inheritDoc%7D)